# Modifying SAT Code To Obtain Penertration Vector

Tags: c++, collision-detection, separating-axis-theorem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SAT, How Do I Find The Penetration Vector?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25543/sat-how-do-i-find-the-penetration-vector)

Hi how could I modify my SAT code and visual debug it to find the penetration vector of the two Entities so I can separate them.

Code:
http://ideone.com/ef7A3

Comment: This is a well-known issue which has well-known answers that wouldn't have taken you more than 20 seconds and two clicks to find out on Google....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There we go: http://www.codezealot.org/archives/55#sat-mtv

Comment: Got anyway to visualize SAT's so I can debug it?

Comment: Alright so I think nobody here really got your question actually. Could you please try to rephrase it? What do you mean by "visualizing SAT"? Not sure to understand what does prevent you from putting a breakpoint into your code anyway...